# Pictures as category axis labels in Amcharts

Tags: javascript, charts, axis, label

Title is quite self-explanatory. Basically what I wish is that I could place HTML code in Amcharts category axis values, e.g. `<img src="photourl.jpg"/>`.

[This is Amcharts 3D column chart sample](http://www.amcharts.com/demos/3d-column-chart/#theme-none). I would want for example to replace the country names with each one's flag image. Anybody knows if this is possible?

Comment: http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that I did read the docs and did not find any answer to what I want. Maybe somebody could suggest a workaround.